# How do I set a scrollbar height within a reactjs return statement?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am currently having an issue with setting the height of my scrollbar. I have found a few methods to set the height of the scrollbar with javascript, but it will not work for my program as I am using reactjs.

I have a chat system which contains a chatbox that is scrollable. There are messages within the chatbox that are set into the chatbox every time the page is rendered:

```
    render() {

         return (

              /*... irrelevant code ...*/

                    <div id = "chat">
                        <div id = "chatBox" className = "chatBox">
                            <AllChatMessages allMessages = {this.props.allMessages} />
                        </div>
                        <form id="chatForm" action = "#">
                            <input id = "chatInput" autoComplete="off" ></input>
                            <button id = "chatSend" type="submit">Send</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

              /*... more irrelevant code ... */

        );
    }
```

I currently have CSS for "chatbox" that looks like:

```
    #chatBox{
        position: relative;
        order: 0;
        width: 42.6em;
        height: 9.7em;
        border: 2px solid #2f5f6f;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
        overflow-y: auto;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .chatBox::-webkit-scrollbar{
        width: 15px;
    }

    .chatBox::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #2f5f6f; 
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    } 

    .chatBox::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: rgba(47,95,111,0.8); 
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }

    .chatBox::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
        background: rgba(47,95,111,1);
    }
```

Since the chatbox only exists after I return the block of code to my website, it seems to me (and i've tried a few ways) that there is no javascript I can use to set the height of the scrollbar to the bottom (because any javascript has to be before the return statement).

Is there any way to auto-set the height of the scrollbar to the bottom in some way that i'm missing? Maybe I can do it with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run javascript after the render is called in react.  You'll have to include the code you want to run in a [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) function attached to the same class as the render.

I think you are trying to set the position of the scrollable content to the bottom of the content. You can use [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) to do this.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
     componentDidMount() {
          let chatBox = document.getElementById('chatBox');
          chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
     }

     render() {...}
}
```

Comment: I haven't been using this function, but this is a great example to cement my understanding of the function. This is exactly what I needed.